# Writing a rikulo table widget to handle large data set?

Tags: widget, dart, rikulo, large-data

I like the table ui example in the rikulo examples with scrollable columns and rows and the fliud motion with the momentum built in. My question is if you wanted to write a table with scroll panes to support ten thousand rows, how would you suggest doing it? I assume the load and rendering under the current demo take a long time. So I think you want have a data cursor system that have a look-ahead preload when the scrolling up/down the table. I thus if you appearance having infinite rows in the table div, but all you have in the DOM is the number of viewable rows plus one or two for transitioning/scrolling. Has anybody tried writing one of these in Rikulo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you already said, you need to implement a viewport mechanism: creating and removing views depending on the scroll position. It can be done by listening the [scrollMove](http://api.rikulo.org/ui/latest/rikulo_event/ViewEvents.html#scrollMove) event:

```
scrollView.on.scrollMove.listen((ScrollEvent event) {
  //remove views that become invisible (leaving the viewpoint)
  //create views that become visible (entering the viewpoint)
```

Since every view in Rikulo is positioned absolutely, so it is straightforward to position them based on the scroll position.